# Couldn't access data in laravel 5.8 from 1 to many relationship

Tags: php, eloquent, routes

I new to laravel. I have been trying to set a 1 to many realtionship between post and category, I can access the category using the post_id but not the reverse. I get the following error,

"Trying to get property 'category' of non-object"

This is my web.php

```
<?php
use App\Post;

Route::get('/test',function()
{
    return App\Post::find(3)->category;

});
```

This is from post.php

```
    public function category() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
```

This is from category.php

```
 public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
```

This is Post.php

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Softdeletes;

class Post extends Model
{

    protected $fillable =[
        'title', 'content', 'category_id', 'featured', 'slug'
    ];

    public function category() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function tag()
    {
        return $this-> belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }

    use SoftDeletes;


    public function getFeaturedAttribute($featured)
    {
        return asset($featured);
    }
.......
```

This is Category.php

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{

protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Comment: A category surely doesn't belong to a category? You probably ment `Post::find(7)->category;`? Or `App\Category::find(7)->posts;`?

Comment: I have edited it to.....    return App\Post::find(3)->category;

Answer (score 0):

The [find method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections#method-find) finds a model that has a given primary key. In your web.php `App\Category::find(7)` returns a category instance of id 7. I'm guessing what you are trying to do is `App\Post::find(7)->category` in other word you are trying to retrieve the post of id 7 and get its category; If not you are probably trying to access the posts of one category of id 7 in which case you should code `App\Category::find(7)->posts`.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to retrieve post of id 7 and get its category. So why am I getting the error?

Comment: @KidusYared you should code `App\Post::find(7)->category` to retrieve post of id 7 and get its category not App\Category::find(7)->category;

Comment: I misstyped the first time, I have edited the code to.....    return App\Post::find(3)->category;

Comment: Nop, Still the Same Problem

Comment: @KidusYared Can you update your post and show your classes App\Category and App\Posts?

Comment: I have Updated it.

Comment: @KidusYared if you still get the non object error please `var_dump(App\Post::find(3));` to see if you actually get a post.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need App\Category::find(7)->posts because Category model really doesn't have category property

Comment: No I checked that, not the problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem was I closed everything and restarted. Everything worked fine.